# How to concat rows text from a list into a success text msg in .Net Core wep api

Tags: asp.net-core, rows, concatenation

concat rows text from a list into a success text msg in .Net Core wep api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has nothing to do with WebAPI itself. It is more of a framework issue. Use **string.Join(delimiter, ienumerable)**.

However, here is an example:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var listOfMessages = new[] {"these", "should", "be", "combined"};
        var result = string.Join(' ', listOfMessages);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 22 May 2018 10:59:38 GMT
Content-Length: 24

these should be combined
```